# Fingerprint sensor in mobile

Tags: java, android, flutter, server

My graduation project is develop application access fingerprint sensor in mobile device and user register fingerprint i want to get fingerprint as image and apply encryption technology and nural network for matching and store in server, what libraries help me i use android studio to develop application?

I am trying develop application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how fingerprint sensors work.  They don't give an image, it's not just a camera.  In fact it would be a really horrible way for a fingerprint sensor to work even if it was a camera-  it would be passing on the secret to whatever app used the sensor.  In Android the fingerprint sensor is used by the OS, and all it returns is whether an attempt to authenticate succeeds or fails vs the prints stored in secured, hardware encrypted storage.